Rails - Redcarpet Markdown Gem - How to change target based on href?
I'm trying to use Redcarpet's :with_toc_data as an option, and it works.
It inserts the 'a name="whatever"' to headers (h1, h2, etc).
My Site users can choose a setting to have links open in a new window (or not).
Setting this in the code is easy:
if request.cookies["open_links_in_new_window"].nil? || (request.cookies["open_links_in_new_window"] == "yes")
target = "_blank" + rand(1000000).to_s
else
target = ""
end

This is called after the options and extensions are set via:
options = {}
extensions = {whatever}
renderer = OurHTML.new(options)
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
markdown.render(text).html_safe

What I would like to do is set the target to nil or "" when an href begins with a "#".
Basically I want to be able to have a TOC in a markdown block.
hrefs that start with "#" will get no target, normal hrefs will get a random target, if the users chose that option.
Unlike the "target" if/then, I can't figure out how to test for the actual href value individually.
I know this is a really specific and weird question.
Any advice would be awesome.

Can you show a bit more code or explain how things belong toghether? Where is the target variable used?
But probably what you're looking for is to postprocess the redcarpet document

Target is the outputted html in the href, so target="_blank".
